# Insert object to vector in alphabetical order c++

Tags: c++, vector, operator-overloading, overloading

My goal is to make simple function that would insert objects to vector by keeping it alphabeticaly sorted so i can later easely search in vector.

This is my simplified example:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

class Names {
public:
    Names(void);
    ~Names(void);
    bool Insert(const string & namer);
private:

    struct Person {
        string name;
    };
    vector<Person>people;
};

Names::Names() {
};

Names::~Names() {
};

bool Names::Insert(const string& namer) {
    Person p;
    p.name = namer;
    people.insert(upper_bound(people.begin(), people.end(), p), p);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Names b1;
    bool status;
    status = b1 . Insert("John Smith");
    status = b1 . Insert("Bat Man");
    status = b1 . Insert("A Aron");
    return 0;
}
```

It doesnt work probably because upper_bound function cant compare string. Can anyone help me how to properly use insert function to insert into right spot ?

Thank you for any help.

Edit:

My problem is that my solution does not work because problems with compilation and i would like to find out why.

Comment: Are you certain that a vector is the best data structure for your purpose? Maybe a map would be worth considering.

Comment: I know map is better but i have to use vector or create my own data structure and i would like to avoid any self made memory allocation problem.

Comment: If you are struck with vector, use `std::sort` after populating all elements to vector.

Comment: Do you have to *insert* in alphabetical order, or is it okay to just insert and then sort afterwards?

Comment: Why do you think `upper_bound` can't compare strings?

Comment: sort is very slow, i cant afford linear complexity

Comment: You'll do much worse than linear complexity inserting on a vector anywhere but the end. Best to fill the vector and then sort.

Comment: Inserting in order and sorting after the fact are both O(n log n) best case. I suspect the sort will be faster overall but you should benchmark it once you get it working.

Comment: `std::string` has an `operator<` so yes the strings will compare and `upper_bound` will work properly. Do you need a case-insensitive compare or something?

Comment: If i insert 1000 objects and sort them and then search for one it would be ok, but if i insert one more after then i would have to sort it once again before i can binary search again. I think that if i insert in right spot every time, i wont have to sort vector every time before i want to search in it.

Comment: Have you thought about things like `á` and `ü` and `œ`...?

Comment: I dont need case sensitive, or other than ASCII chars.

Comment: `upper_bound` should work just fine, but you'll need to define `operator<` for `Person`, or provide a comparison functor.

Comment: @TomášPastorek: Not needing other than ASCII-7 in a `class Names` is a funny POV for someone having *two* non-ASCII-7 characters in his first name. I sure hope this is homework, and I sure hope your instructor *does* tell you the importance of i18n.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should define `operator <` for class Person. For example it can be a member function of the class

```
struct Person {
    bool operator <( const pserson &rhs ) const { return ( name < rhs.name ); }
    string name;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `std::sort`.

Takes three arguments,

```
Sort(your_vector.begin(),your_vector.end(),predicate)
```

You can define your predicate function to sort objects alphabetically.